# How do I check if an Observable value is populated in Angular?

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I want some data to be centrally loaded in the app through a single HTTP request and want this data to be passed on to multiple individual components. I am using the BehaviourSubject class to set the data loaded into an observable object in a shared service and am subscribing to it in individual components.

SharedService:

```
  data: Observable<any>;

  load_data(){
  this.http.post('/myAPIMethod', {myInputs}).subscribe(
      res => {
              var dataSource=new BehaviorSubject(res);
              this.data = dataSource.asObservable();
          }, error => {
          console.log(error);
      });
  }
```

app.component.ts:

```
constructor(private shared: SharedService) { }
ngOnInit(){
  this.shared.load_data();
  }
```

myComponent.component.ts

```
constructor(private shared: SharedService) { }
ngAfterViewInit(){
  this.shared.data.subscribe(
      res => {console.log(res)},
      err => {console.log(err)}
    );
}
```

Since my app.component.ts and myComponent.component.ts files are loading asynchronously and independently, I am getting an error when it tries to subscribe to the 'data' Observable in myComponent even before the app has loaded the data. I get a subscribed of undefined error ('data' is  undefined and it is already trying to subscribe).

How do I check for the 'data' Observable value being set before subscribing to it in the myComponent file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Subject`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/subjects/subject.html) instead:

```
data = new Subject();

load_data(){
  this.http.post('/myAPIMethod', {myInputs}).subscribe(
      res => {
              this.data.next(res);
          }, error => {
          console.log(error);
      });
}
```

This way your components can subscribe to the `Subject` before the data is return, and it emit the data when the http call received.

Additionally, if are you not going to manipulate the DOM / View elements in your subscribe function then call it inside `ngOnInit` instead:
yourComponet.ts

```
ngOnInit(){
  this.shared.data.subscribe(
      res => {console.log(res)},
      err => {console.log(err)}
    );
```

Comment: It worked. So based on this, the Subject emits when it is initialised and even when no value is assigned ( new Subject line) whereas and observable actually needs some value to be set before it can be accessed? Is my understanding right?

Comment: Both can be subscribed before the data is returned, the different is subject gonna multicast the data while observable gonna unicast it

Comment: I used subject since i though your intend is to multicast the data, but if it is not you can just `return this.http.post('/myAPIMethod', {myInputs})` in `load_data()`, then subscribe to it in the component

Comment: Oh alright, so then the error I got must have been because the observable had already been called in some other component and so the second component that made the same call could not load the data any more, correct? And Now with Subject, since it is multicast, it is able to load it in multiple components in parallel, correct?

Comment: And yes, my intention is to call in multiple components.

Comment: The errors happened because you subscribed to `data` while it is not assigned any value ( it type is defined, but the value is not assign). And multicasting and unicasting is quite different from what you seeing them now. I would suggest to have a look at this article https://www.johndpotts.com/2018-09-10-subjects-vs-observables-multicasting/